# Html body not covering full screen in case of larger screen resolutions like 2048px

Tags: html, css

In case of iPad portrait mode or screen resolutions more than 1920px, the html body leaves a blank space on the right and every element shows white space on the right and this space gets wider with the increasing screen resolution

I have set padding and margin to 0 in the body
Moreover, I have set width 100% but the same problem persists

```
body {
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  width: 100% !important;   }
```

I am expecting that there would be no white space on the right by adding the above code to body but it is leaving some space

Comment: We cannot guess what it is with just the `body`properties

Comment: @Dev you don't have to use !important

Comment: please re-edit your question and add some code whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```